# From the binding energy curve can we say anything about the energy released by the fission of heavier nuclei like uranium?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy

From the binding energy curve can we say anything about the energy released by the fission of heavier nuclei like uranium?

Answer (score 1):

The binding energy curve that you are probably referring to shows binding energy 'per nucleon'.

If the Uranium splits up and makes two elements, Barium and Krypton and they are higher on the curve than the original uranium, then energy is released, just as when two Hydrogens fuse to make Helium and Helium is higher on the curve, energy is also released.

[image]

From [this](https://www.miniphysics.com/binding-energy-per-nucleon-and-nuclear.html) website